# Django forms to update DB data

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am creating an invoice app. Trying to update saved data in DB. Django traceback gives error.

> 'User' object has no attribute 'get'

**Forms.py**

```
class createinvoiceformedit(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = serviceinvoice
        exclude = ('user',)
        widgets = {
            'invoice_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
        }
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def edit_invoice(request):
    new_formset=createinvoiceformsetedit(instance=serviceinvoice())
    if request.method == 'POST':
        invoice = serviceinvoice.objects.get(id__exact=id)
        inv_form=createinvoiceformedit(data=request.POST,user=request.user,instance=invoice)        
        if inv_form.is_valid():
            new_form=inv_form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.user=request.user
            new_formset=createinvoiceformsetedit(request.POST,instance=new_form)
            if new_formset.is_valid():
                new_form.save()
                hero=new_formset.save(commit=False)
                for hero1 in hero:
                    hero1.user=request.user
                    hero1.save()
                return HttpResponse('Invoice created')
    else:
        inv_form=createinvoiceformedit(request.user)
    return render(request,'account/editinvoice.html',{'inv_form':inv_form,'new_formset':new_formset})
```

**Templates**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Create Invoice{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Add Invoice</h1>

<form action="." method="post">
<table><tr>
{{ inv_form.as_table }}</tr></table>
{{ new_formset.non_form_errors.as_ul }}
<table id="formset" class="form">
{{ new_formset.management_form }}
{% for form in new_formset.forms %}
{% if forloop.first %}
<thead><tr>
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
<th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
{% endfor %}
</tr></thead>
{% endif %}
<tr class="{% cycle row1,row2 %}">
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
<td>
{# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
{% if forloop.first %}
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
{{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{{ field.errors.as_ul }}
{{ field }}
</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
<tr>
<th></th>
<td>
{% csrf_token %}<input type="submit" value="Create Invoice"></td></tr></table>
</form>
```

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/invoice/editinvoice/

Django Version: 1.8.9
Python Version: 3.4.0
Installed Applications:
('invoice',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:

    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
      132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\pythonspace\tiktant\invoice\views.py" in edit_invoice
      123.     product = serviceinvoice.objects.get(id__exact=id)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
      127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
      325.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
      679.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
      697.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
      1310.         clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
      1338.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
      1156.         value, lookups, used_joins = self.prepare_lookup_value(value, lookups, can_reuse, allow_joins)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in prepare_lookup_value
      1003.             value = value()

    Exception Type: TypeError at /invoice/editinvoice/
    Exception Value: id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Am I doing it right way or something missing?

Comment: Can you put the full traceback?  It's hard to see which of the lines is throwing the error without it.

Comment: @Withnail updated question.

Comment: Your traceback does not say `'User' object has no attribute 'get'` anywhere. Your view `def edit_invoice(request):` does not accept an argument `id`, so what do expect `invoice = serviceinvoice.objects.get(id__exact=id)` to do?

Comment: @Alasdair I  made some changes in views may be. But I am really stuck with this thing. How do I edit my saved data using forms in django!!!!

Comment: @Alasdair An example please, you have helped a lot in learning Django.

Comment: Sorry, I won't write your code for you. I've given you two ideas to get started. Fix your question so that the code matches the error message, and think about where `id` is meant to come from.

Comment: @Alasdair Do you have link which explains How to edit DB data. Googling from 2 days but could not find a simple and easy example.

Comment: Slightly out of date, but I agree with Alasdair's points.  I'd have a read of either this (slightly out of date, but mostly valid), or the django tutorial again.  http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/index.html

Comment: Thanks guys finally a message Invoice Edited, made my day. Now to look for how to edit the linked item form, its a inlineformset_factory. Any tutorial. Withnail thanks for pointing.